# Upper bound on the entries of the Gram matrix of a semi-orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is a semi-orthogonal matrix, meaning that $\mathbf{X^\top X=I_m}$. Is there a way to bound the entries of $\mathbf{XX^\top}$?

A simple bound I found is

$$(\mathbf{XX}^T)_{ij}=\mathbf{X}_i(\mathbf{X}_j)^T\leq \Vert \mathbf{X}_i\Vert\Vert \mathbf{X}_j\Vert$$
and so
$$\max_{ij}\ (\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top)_{ij}\ \leq\ \max_{ij}\ \Vert \mathbf{X}_i\Vert\Vert \mathbf{X}_j\Vert \ =\ \max_i\Vert \mathbf{X}_i\Vert\times\max_{j\neq i}\Vert \mathbf{X}_j\Vert$$

Comment: Yes, their moduli are at most $1$.

Comment: I'm looking for a tighter bound, for example wrt the dimensions of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$

Comment: Since $\pmatrix{I&0}\pmatrix{I\\ 0}=I$, the upper bound $1$ is already tight.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think that I wasn't clear enough, I meant a bound given some characteristic of matrix $\mathbf{X}$. I've updated the question.

Comment: Qtip, among other things, the characteristic polynomial of $X X^T$ is just $x^{n-m}$ times the characteristic polynomial of $X^T  X  $  which was $(x-1)^m$  There is also a construction, using Gram Schmidt, that goes with this. Indeed, take $X^T$   and complete it to an orthogonal matrix, call it $M.$   Then $MX $   is of the form of @user1551  's   rectangular matrices, the one on the right.   Next  $M X X^T M^T $   is a square matrix with the identity in the upper left and else all $0,$  call that   $J,$    then $XX^T =  M^T J M.$  Food for thought